# Domain redirect doesn't work when clicked from Google search result

Tags: dns, google-search

I have redirects set up for juliaomalley.media > juliaomalley.com

Typing the old (.media) domain into your browser bar will correctly redirect you to the new (.com) site.

But if you do a Google search and click on the old Google listing for the .media domain, it gives a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and doesn't redirect.

What am I doing wrong? The hosting account that hosted the old site that the .media domain *had* been pointing to has been deleted, so I can't add anything to .htaccess there or anything like that.

Namecheap domain setting below:

[image]

Comment: The redirect works for `http://juliaomalley.media`, but google has indexed secure (https) urls, so `https://juliaomalley.media`.

Comment: @DusanBajic This point about the HTTPS version not redirecting pointed me in the right direction. I'd mark it as the solution if you wanted to submit it as an answer.

Comment: @Lime if you figured out the issue, please make an edit showing how. The answer you selected does not resolve the issue on it's own.

Comment: @TrevorO'Farrell Jeez, sorry. I don't recall. If I remember correctly, what I thought fixed this when I made the above comment didn't actually work. I don't remember now if it was eventually a matter of getting Google to recrawl enough, or possibly if I just waited for the old .media domain to fall out of search listings (aided by Search Console of course). Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect works for `http://juliaomalley.media`, but google has indexed secure (https) urls, so `https://juliaomalley.media`

Answer (score 2):

When did you make this change?

I must admit I'm getting  the same result as you from a Google Search.

However, a cURL lookup does show the correct HTTP redirect being given by Namescheap.

```
$ curl -iL juliaomalley.media
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 23 Aug 2021 18:00:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 51
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.juliaomalley.com
X-Served-By: Namecheap URL Forward

HTTP/2 301
date: Mon, 23 Aug 2021 18:00:52 GMT
server: Apache
x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.16
x-redirect-by: WordPress
location: https://juliaomalley.com/
vary: User-Agent
content-length: 0
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

HTTP/2 200
date: Mon, 23 Aug 2021 18:00:53 GMT
server: Apache
vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
last-modified: Fri, 20 Aug 2021 15:27:07 GMT
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 37496
cache-control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The only thing that jumps to my mind is that Google have cached the result for the search and are directing to the old hosting company.
If you have access to the Google Webmaster account for this domain try starting a new index run as this (I hope) should update the results.